# Does hangfire support every x years?

Tags: cron, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire 1.7.31, as I can see it only support 6 parts of cron.
However, my requirement is to trigger a job every two years.

Can hangfire be used for this scenario?

Comment: is it supported by cron expression ?, if yes then you can specify the complete cron expression as string while creating job.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set a cronexpression to fire at a specific date every year.
As per https://crontab.guru/every-year you can use following cron expression:
`0 0 1 1 *`, whichs translates to:
`At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in January.`